# How to Enable Mixed precision training

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, half-precision-float, automatic-mixed-precision

i'm trying to train a deep learning model on **vs code** so i would like to use the **GPU** for that. I have **cuda 11.6** , **nvidia GeForce GTX 1650**,  **TensorFlow-gpu==2.5.0**  and **pip version 21.2.3** for **windows 10**. The problem is whenever i run this part of code i've got this **error :  Mixed precision training with AMP or APEX (`--fp16` or `--bf16`) and half precision evaluation (`--fp16_full_eval` or `--bf16_full_eval`) can only be used on CUDA devices.**

```
from transformers import TrainingArguments

training_args = TrainingArguments(
output_dir=new_output_models_dir,
#output_dir="dev/",
group_by_length=True,
per_device_train_batch_size=16,
gradient_accumulation_steps=2,
#dataloader_num_workers = 1,
dataloader_num_workers = 0,
evaluation_strategy="steps",
num_train_epochs=40,
fp16=True,
save_steps=400,
eval_steps=400,
logging_steps=400,
learning_rate=1e-4,
warmup_steps=500,
save_total_limit=2,
)
```

I've also tested whether tensorflow can access a gpu and whether tensorflow was built with cuda gpu support using **tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')** and **tf.test.is_built_with_cuda()** and both of them return **TRUE** . How to slove this issue ? and why i'm getting this error ? Any ideas !

Answer (score 1):

The above error suggests that it does not accept fp16=True/bf16=True in non-GPU mode. Perhaps Cuda 11.6 might be an issue here which has  stability issues.

Test with Cuda 11.2 and CudNN 8.1 . If that does not work you can go with fp16=False parametre.

Ref - https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu